# E(Y|X) given their joint pdf and X=1

Tags: self-study, expected-value

Suppose the joint pdf of $x,y$ is given by $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-p^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2-2pxy}{2(1-p^2)}}$ $-\infty<x,y<\infty$

What is $E(Y|X=1)$?

I tried substituting $X=1$ so:

$$f(1,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-p^2}}e^{-\frac{1+y^2-2py}{2(1-p^2)}}$$
for :$-\infty<y<\infty$

But $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf(1,y)$ does not seem doable. I did some manipulations with the exponent and ended up with:

$$f(1,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-p^2}}e^{-\frac{(y-p)^2}{2(1-p^2)}-\frac{1}{2}}$$

Which seems eerily relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to calculate the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$, i.e. $f_Y(y|X=1) = \frac{f(1,y)}{f_X(1)}$, where $f_X(x)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \, dy$ is the marginal distribution of $X$ and afterwards calculate $$\mathbb{E}(Y|X=1) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y f_Y(y|X=1) \, dy.$$

However, in your case $(X,Y)$ are multivariate Normal distributed. Hence the conditional distribution of $Y|X$ is multivariate Normal.

Since in your case we have $\mu_X = 0=\mu_Y$  and $\sigma_X = \sigma_Y=1$ you have $$\mathbb{E}(Y|X=1) = \rho \cdot 1.$$
which you could use as a check after you have done your calculations.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#In_the_case_of_unit_variances).